# Adding a global variable to each row of a parsed JSON

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

To enable daily reporting from a system I am calling an api each day and returning some of its values before copying these values into a google sheet. This will run automaically each day, gathering the previous day's data.

The code below works and is correctly pulling the data and pasting it into the sheet, however what I would like to do is add the value of the variable 'yesterday' into column A of each row.

```
function getDataAndParse() {
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("fmsdata");
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var today = new Date();
  var yday = new Date();
  yday.setDate(today.getDate() -1);
  var yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yday, "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  url = "http://example.com/GetData?" + "&Date=" + yesterday;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  
  var parseData = JSON.parse(content);
  var values = parseData.d.map(({key1, key2, key3}) => key1, key2, key3]);
  
  dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

An example of how the data is structured is here

```
{"d":[
{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"},
{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"},
{"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"}
]}
```

This returns:
value, value, value
value, value, value
value, value, value

However what I would like to return is:
yesterday, value, value, value
yesterday, value, value, value
yesterday, value, value, value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var table = parseData.map(x => [yesterday, x.key1, x.key2, x.key3]);
```

```js
var data = `{"d":[
    {"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"},
    {"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"},
    {"key1":"value","key2":"value","key3":"value"}
    ]}`

var yesterday = "yesterday";

var parseData = JSON.parse(data);

var table = parseData.d.map(x => [yesterday, x.key1, x.key2, x.key3]);

console.log(table);
```

Output:

```
┌─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ (index) │      0      │    1    │    2    │    3    │
├─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│    0    │ 'yesterday' │ 'value' │ 'value' │ 'value' │
│    1    │ 'yesterday' │ 'value' │ 'value' │ 'value' │
│    2    │ 'yesterday' │ 'value' │ 'value' │ 'value' │
└─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: I actually can't believe it was that simple - I assumed I couldn't do it that way so hadn't tried. Many thanks!